# What does Block_locator.mli in tezos-base do?

Tags: tezos-base

Can someone help me with role of interface [block_locator.mli](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/mainnet/src/lib_base/block_locator.mli) in tezos-base?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The block locator is used to synchronize two nodes : each node sends a block locator to the other one at connection initialization, so that they can evaluate how far they are on the blockchain. If they are already up-to-date with the last block, the block locator will be very similar. If one of them is not up-to-date, the block locator will tell them how much it will have to work (download blocks and validate them) to get up-to-date with the other one.